# How to use \ContinuedFloat and avoid the text moving up?

Tags: tables, subfloats, layout

I want to write a paper, and do not want the `text` after the figure to move up.

[image]

[image]

I want the flow like this below:
[image]

My WME:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:sub-smoothing}
        \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}        
\begin{figure}[h!]\ContinuedFloat
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}  
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:sub-smoothing1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include second image
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:sub-smoothing2}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
    \end{figure}



\begin{figure}[h!]
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:sub-smoothing}
        \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}        
\begin{figure}[h!]\ContinuedFloat
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}  
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:sub-smoothing1}
        \end{subfigure}
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include second image
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:sub-smoothing2}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
    \end{figure}



    
    

An essay plan helps you organise your ideas and you can be modified as you read, think
or discuss more. It is a basic outline of your essay and is useful if you want to discuss
your writing with your lecturer, tutor or with an Academic Support person.
Here is an example of an essay topic and a possible plan. (Note that the thesis statement
and topic sentences have been written as complete sentences, rather than just as dot
points. Writing them out fully helps you formulate the idea or argument clearly).
Essay question / topic
For most individuals, sporting activities are not associated with any material
rewards. Discuss the possible motives which individuals might have for playing
sport? Include in your discussion examples of your own or other people’s
participation in sport.
Introduction
Sport is regularly played by a considerable percentage of the Australian
population each week. However, many of these people are not seeking some
kind of material reward (such as a premiership trophy, prize money or X). They
often have other kinds of motivations for participating in sporting activities.
Possible thesis statements
Possible motives for playing sport will be outlined in this essay and some
examples from my own and other people’s experience will be used to illustrate
this further.
People play sport for various reasons, including 1, 2, 3 and 4. These are
discussed here using examples from my own experiences and those of two of
my fellow students.
This essay discusses possible motivations people have for engaging in sporting
activities, such as XX, YY and ZZ. Examples of my own participation in a team
sport as well as my friend’s participation in an individual sport will be given to
illustrate these motivations. 
An essay plan helps you organise your ideas and you can be modified as you read, think
or discuss more. It is a basic outline of your essay and is useful if you want to discuss
your writing with your lecturer, tutor or with an Academic Support person.
Here is an example of an essay topic and a possible plan. (Note that the thesis statement
and topic sentences have been written as complete sentences, rather than just as dot
points. Writing them out fully helps you formulate the idea or argument clearly).
Essay question / topic
For most individuals, sporting activities are not associated with any material
rewards. Discuss the possible motives which individuals might have for playing
sport? Include in your discussion examples of your own or other people’s
participation in sport.
Introduction
Sport is regularly played by a considerable percentage of the Australian
population each week. However, many of these people are not seeking some
kind of material reward (such as a premiership trophy, prize money or X). They
often have other kinds of motivations for participating in sporting activities.
Possible thesis statements
Possible motives for playing sport will be outlined in this essay and some
examples from my own and other people’s experience will be used to illustrate
this further.
People play sport for various reasons, including 1, 2, 3 and 4. These are
discussed here using examples from my own experiences and those of two of
my fellow students.
This essay discusses possible motivations people have for engaging in sporting
activities, such as XX, YY and ZZ. Examples of my own participation in a team
sport as well as my friend’s participation in an individual sport will be given to
illustrate these motivations. 

% \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: continuedfloat just affects the numbering not the position.  I suspect you want `\clearpage`

Comment: it isn't that the text moves up, the C float moves down. Allowing such movement is the only function of the `figure` environment,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are preventing the desired layout by using `[!h]` so preventing the **t**op position that you need for C

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}

%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a} 
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:sub-smoothing}
        \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}        
\begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}  
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:sub-smoothing1}
        \end{subfigure}%%%%%%%Needed
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include second image
            \includegraphics[width=0.8\linewidth]{example-image-a}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:sub-smoothing2}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
    \end{figure}



\begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-b} 
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:sub-smoothing}
        \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}        
\clearpage    
\begin{figure}
        \begin{subfigure}{0.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include first image
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}  
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:sub-smoothing1}
        \end{subfigure}%%%%%%%Needed
        \begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
            \centering
            % include second image
            \includegraphics[width=0.2\linewidth]{example-image-c}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig:sub-smoothing2}
        \end{subfigure}
    \caption{}
    \end{figure}



    

An essay plan helps you organise your ideas and you can be modified as you read, think
or discuss more. It is a basic outline of your essay and is useful if you want to discuss
your writing with your lecturer, tutor or with an Academic Support person.
Here is an example of an essay topic and a possible plan. (Note that the thesis statement
and topic sentences have been written as complete sentences, rather than just as dot
points. Writing them out fully helps you formulate the idea or argument clearly).
Essay question / topic
For most individuals, sporting activities are not associated with any material
rewards. Discuss the possible motives which individuals might have for playing
sport? Include in your discussion examples of your own or other people’s
participation in sport.
Introduction
Sport is regularly played by a considerable percentage of the Australian
population each week. However, many of these people are not seeking some
kind of material reward (such as a premiership trophy, prize money or X). They
often have other kinds of motivations for participating in sporting activities.
Possible thesis statements
Possible motives for playing sport will be outlined in this essay and some
examples from my own and other people’s experience will be used to illustrate
this further.
People play sport for various reasons, including 1, 2, 3 and 4. These are
discussed here using examples from my own experiences and those of two of
my fellow students.
This essay discusses possible motivations people have for engaging in sporting
activities, such as XX, YY and ZZ. Examples of my own participation in a team
sport as well as my friend’s participation in an individual sport will be given to
illustrate these motivations. 
An essay plan helps you organise your ideas and you can be modified as you read, think
or discuss more. It is a basic outline of your essay and is useful if you want to discuss
your writing with your lecturer, tutor or with an Academic Support person.
Here is an example of an essay topic and a possible plan. (Note that the thesis statement
and topic sentences have been written as complete sentences, rather than just as dot
points. Writing them out fully helps you formulate the idea or argument clearly).
Essay question / topic
For most individuals, sporting activities are not associated with any material
rewards. Discuss the possible motives which individuals might have for playing
sport? Include in your discussion examples of your own or other people’s
participation in sport.
Introduction
Sport is regularly played by a considerable percentage of the Australian
population each week. However, many of these people are not seeking some
kind of material reward (such as a premiership trophy, prize money or X). They
often have other kinds of motivations for participating in sporting activities.
Possible thesis statements
Possible motives for playing sport will be outlined in this essay and some
examples from my own and other people’s experience will be used to illustrate
this further.
People play sport for various reasons, including 1, 2, 3 and 4. These are
discussed here using examples from my own experiences and those of two of
my fellow students.
This essay discusses possible motivations people have for engaging in sporting
activities, such as XX, YY and ZZ. Examples of my own participation in a team
sport as well as my friend’s participation in an individual sport will be given to
illustrate these motivations. 

% \lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. it work. However, if we did not use `\ContinuedFloat`, the Figure number will mess up. For example: It will label as `Figure 2` then `Figure 4`.

Comment: @aan sure yes you can put the `\ContinuedFloat` back I removed them to concentrate on your question about the float position. `\ContinuedFloat` does not affect the position, it just affects the numbering.

Comment: thanks, it work!